# -complete=file without extra processing of the arguments

Tags: vimscript, autocompletion

Without `-complete=file`:

```
command! -nargs=* C1 echo <q-args>
C1 fzf#vim#grep /home/yuri/.vim/pack/foo/start/fzf.vim
" fzf#vim#grep /home/yuri/.vim/pack/foo/start/fzf.vim
```

With `-complete=file`:

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=file C1 echo <q-args>
C1 fzf#vim#grep /home/yuri/.vim/pack/foo/start/fzf.vim
" fzf/home/yuri/.vim/pack/foo/start/fzf.vim/plugin/fzf.vimvim/home/yuri/.vim/pack/foo/start/fzf.vim/plugin/fzf.vimgrep /home/yuri/.vim/pack/foo/start/fzf.vim
```

That is, it expands `#`'s and supposedly does some other [scary stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636068/vim-plugin-custom-auto-complete-of-params-in-command-mode#comment17047611_12636753) I don't understand. (Can you explain what exactly it does?) More importantly, any suggestions? Custom completion? In that case, any implementation, or an idea of it?

---

I'm trying to create a custom `fzf` command. What I have right now:

```
function! Rgp(bang, ...)
    let pattern = a:0 == 1 ? '' : a:1
    let path = a:0 == 1 ? a:1 : a:2
    call fzf#vim#grep(
    \     'rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case -- ' . shellescape(pattern),
    \     1,
    \     fzf#vim#with_preview({'dir': path}),
    \     a:bang)
endfunction
command! -bang -nargs=* Rgp call Rgp(<bang>0, <f-args>)

" Rgp fzf#vim#grep /home/yuri/.vim/pack/foo/start/fzf.vim
" Rgp /home/yuri/.vim/pack/foo/start/fzf.vim
```

Comment: For the expansion, see `:help cmdline-special`. Not sure why it affects parsing though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea on using custom completion to implement file completion without triggering the side effect of expanding `#` and similar special characters!

You can do slightly better by using a Vimscript built-in to get the completion candidates instead of spawning a shell and using `compgen`. Vim has the [`getcompletion()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getcompletion%28%29) function that returns valid completions for a specific arglead with a given completion context.

In your case, it allows implementing file completion as a one-liner too:

```
function! C1Complete(lead, _, _)
    return getcompletion(a:lead, 'file', 1)
endfunction
command! -nargs=* -complete=customlist,C1Complete C1 echo <q-args>
```

(Note that this uses `customlist`, since the function returns a list already filtered for the arglead.)

I found that this also behaves slightly better than the `compgen` version in terms of UX, for example, when you complete a directory name with this version it will add a trailing dash which helps when completing paths under that directory. (The `compgen` version requires you to add slashes manually.)

Completion using this method is slightly less convenient than when using `-complete=file`. For example, when `'wildmenu'` is enabled and you have multiple options deep in a directory tree, `-complete=file` will only show the entries for the last level in the wildmenu, while `-complete=customlist,...` (or `custom` too) will show the full paths, which makes them take more space and make the menu less convenient, but probably still usable in most cases... In any case, these differences are the same as with the `compgen` method in your self-answer, which you said was acceptable to you, so perhaps this is a small but welcome enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out relatively simple:

```
function! C1Complete(ArgLead, CmdLine, CursorPos)
    return system('compgen -f ' . shellescape(a:ArgLead))
endfunction
command! -nargs=* -complete=custom,C1Complete C1 echo <q-args>

C1 fzf#vim#grep /home/yuri/.vim/pack/foo/start/fzf.vim
" fzf#vim#grep /home/yuri/.vim/pack/foo/start/fzf.vim
```

And the `Rgp` command:

```
" https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/d6aa21476b2854694e6aa7b0941b8992a906c5ec/plugin/fzf.vim#L57
function! Rgp(bang, ...)
    let pattern = a:0 == 1 ? '' : a:1
    let path = a:0 == 1 ? a:1 : a:2
    call fzf#vim#grep(
    \     'rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case -- ' . shellescape(pattern),
    \     1,
    \     fzf#vim#with_preview({'dir': path}),
    \     a:bang)
endfunction

function! RgpComplete(ArgLead, CmdLine, CursorPos)
    return system('compgen -f ' . shellescape(a:ArgLead))
endfunction

command! -bang -nargs=* -complete=custom,RgpComplete Rgp call Rgp(<bang>0, <f-args>)
```

Although it will autocomplete all arguments ([WORD](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#WORD)s), but for now that is not an issue for me.